# Table Partitioning in Azure SQL DW based on Cust_Id/Tenant_Id (Multi-tenancy)?

Tags: database, ssas, partitioning, multi-tenant, azure-synapse

I am new to MS BI stack and trying to create a partition on a SQL DW table field i.e. cust_id which is unique for each customer (tenant_id) and present in every table, so that every customer’s data remains in their respective partitions, without impacting others.

Below is the table structure, data and output from the partitions:

```
create table emp
(
cust_id integer not null,
emp_id varchar(5) not null,
emp_name varchar(10) not null
)
with 
(
  clustered columnstore index
 ,distribution = round_robin
 ,partition (cust_id range right for values (100,200,300) )
)

create table dept
(
cust_id integer not null,
dept_id varchar(5) not null,
emp_id varchar(5) not null,
dep_name varchar(10) not null
)
with 
(
  clustered columnstore index
 ,distribution = round_robin
 ,partition (cust_id range right for values (100,200,300) )
)

create statistics emp_stats on dbo.emp(cust_id)
create statistics dept_stats on dbo.dept(cust_id)

emp table:
101 EMP01   XYZ
101 EMP02   ABC
101 EMP03   DEF
201 EE001   JACK
201 EE002   MIKE

dept table:
cust_id dept_id emp_id  dep_name
101 D0001   EMP01   IT
101 D0001   EMP02   IT
201 DEP01   EE001   ENG
201 DEP02   EE002   HR


 SELECT sch.name AS [schema_name],
       tbl.[name] AS [table_name],
       ds.type_desc,
       prt.[partition_number],
       rng.[value] AS [current_partition_range_boundary_value],
       prt.[rows] AS [partition_rows]    
FROM   sys.schemas sch
       INNER JOIN sys.tables tbl    ON  sch.schema_id       = tbl.schema_id
       INNER JOIN sys.partitions prt    ON  prt.[object_id]     = tbl.[object_id]
       INNER JOIN sys.indexes idx   ON  prt.[object_id]     = idx.[object_id] AND prt.[index_id] = idx.[index_id]
       INNER JOIN sys.data_spaces               ds  ON  idx.[data_space_id] = ds.[data_space_id]                       
       INNER JOIN sys.partition_schemes     ps  ON  ds.[data_space_id]  = ps.[data_space_id]                
       INNER JOIN sys.partition_functions       pf  ON  ps.[function_id]    = pf.[function_id]              
       LEFT JOIN sys.partition_range_values rng ON  pf.[function_id]    = rng.[function_id] AND rng.[boundary_id] = prt.[partition_number]    
WHERE      tbl.name in ('emp','dept')
order by table_name, partition_number


schema_name table_name  type_desc   partition_number    current_partition_range_boundary_value  partition_rows
dbo dept    PARTITION_SCHEME    1   100 1
dbo dept    PARTITION_SCHEME    2   200 1
dbo dept    PARTITION_SCHEME    3   300 1
dbo dept    PARTITION_SCHEME    4   NULL    1
dbo emp PARTITION_SCHEME    1   100 1
dbo emp PARTITION_SCHEME    2   200 1
dbo emp PARTITION_SCHEME    3   300 1
dbo emp PARTITION_SCHEME    4   NULL    2
```

Questions/Clarifications:

```
1)  Whether the partition created on cust_id (tenant_id) field along with round_robin distribution method correct? What is the right way to do it? Need to segregate the customer specific data for both performance (load + query) & security reasons.
2)  How can we load specific customer data into their respective partition (cust_id) – syntax in SQL DW? 
insert into emp (partition = <partition_name_number> ) ?
3)  How do I verify that the data is getting loaded into correct respective partition as I am unable to understand the output from above query as to how it is showing 4 partitions and only 1 row for cust_id 101 in emp table when actually there are 3 ? Was expecting that since 101 is between 100 and 200, it should be in partition_number = 1  and 201 which is between 200 and 300 in partition_number = 2? Is this a wrong assumption on how partition range works? Can’t we simply have a List partition created in SQL DW for each cust_id ?
4)  As per MS documentation, it by default divides each table into 60 distributed databases and that there should be at least 1M per distribution for a partition. When you don’t know how many customer’s data and their volume you may have in future, how do we approach towards it ?
5)  When creating semantic layer (Analysis Services-SSAS) on top of DW, is it helpful to do further do partition on tenant_id or some other field?
```

Thanks for your help, inputs and suggestions !!

Answer (score 0):

Partitioning is available on Azure SQL Data Warehouse, but the documentation comes with a warning that it may be counter-productive. Your example may be a good case.

You should look to distribution rather than partitioning to make sure that your data is optimally aligned across the nodes.

Don't use round_robin distribution unless there is a strong reason that you can't use hash or replication. Round-robin will load fast, but subsequent queries on that table will be slow.

Are you implementing a dimensional model? How many customers do you have? The general guidance is to REPLICATE dimensions unless they are very large (1B+ rows) in which case they may be the drive the hash distribution strategy.

Comment: Appreciate your valuable inputs Ron !! However, I am not implementing any dimensional model at this point, but a simple relational model in SQL DW (no constraints) and then a Tabular Analysis Service (SSAS) semantic model on top of SQL DW for doing further calculations, aggregations, converting into business specific names, hiding unwanted columns etc. I am still at the design phase and don’t have any customers yet; but it could be any number in future and probably this is where I feel the major challenge could be.

Comment: Primary reasons as to why am looking for partitioning on cust_id(tenant_id) is because:
1) Customer data should be segregated so that one customer’s data loads, query and performance does not impact other customers data (rows) in the same table. 
2) Some customer’s data load requirements may differ from others. For some it could be just monthly load once, for some could be daily incremental (with delta) etc.
3) Data should be secured (via row level security) so that customer’s cannot view others data.

Comment: 1) How do I create partitions in SQL DW tables (relational) on cust_id/tenant_id which I tried (as in my above notes) but doesn’t look like it is distributing/storing rows into the desired partition for respective customer/tenant? What is it that I may be doing incorrect or not following correctly ? 2) What is the syntax if I need to load a specific customers data into their respective partition only? Something like: insert into dbo.emp ($partition = 1) ;Where partition number 1 is for cust_id 101, 2 for 102, 3 for 103 and so on (this can be parameterized though)

Comment: 3) Also, when implementing row level security/roles, need to make sure that specific customer is able to only view their slice of data quickly from their specific logical partition. How this should be done? Something like: select * from dbo.emp (partition = 1) OR select * from dbo.emp where cust_id = <101>. With respect to Replication & Hash distribution rather then Round Robin; in the relational SQL DW model there could be both master (small) and events/transactional data (large) tables; but considering the fact that the same table may hold rows for many customers (multi-tenancy) in future.

Comment: I think replication might be okay initially for small tables, but later it may need to be designed again for storing more customer’s data. Right ? Per some online MS guidelines on choosing right distribution methods, we need to choose keys which has many unique values, not used in the Where clause but in Join,GroupBy, Distinct,Having clause. When it’s not a fact/dimension table and cust_id will be repetitive for each row in the table for a customer and used in the where clause to filter out specific customer or tenant’s data, then would it still make sense to go with hash distribution ? Thanks

Comment: Wow! That's a lot to deal with in StackOverflow comments. Drop me an email ... ron dot dunn at microsoft dot com ... and we'll discuss in more detail.

Comment: Sure, that would be great !! Thanks.